# Generate incremental sequence number in teradata

Tags: sql, sequence, teradata

I have a scenario that there will be 2 tables.

1. scratch.data_table
2. scratch.temp_table

scratch.data_table will have one of the field as sequence_id in incremental way like 4000,4001,4002

Other table   scratch.temp_table will have other columns same as scratch.data_table  but except sequence_id column

`scratch.temp_table` will have 5 records and I want to take `max` of `sequence_id` from `scratch.data_table` i.e 4002

and insert it into the same table scratch.data_table from 5 records of scratch.temp_table

Result should be like:

```
4000 | a | b | c
4001 | x | y | z
4002 | s | t | d
4003 | d | t | f   --> d|t|f is the records from scratch.temp_table and 4003 is the incremental value
4004 | d | g | h
4005 | g | t | h
4006 | y | u | i
4007 | y | y | t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    coalesce((select max(sequence_id) from data_table),0)
    + row_number() over (order by not_too_skewed_column_eg_PI)
 , t.*
from temp_table as t
```

Or you keep a sequence table where you store the current max in one row per table